# how to make a button change from pause to play

Tags: javascript

When I run the code bellow, I expect the button to change from pause to play, and vise versa.
What can I do to get the button from pause to play?
I used this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8_wEZD160g.
Thanks!!

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div#video_controls_bar {
            padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
         <script>
             function playPause(btn, vid){
                 var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
                 vid.load();
             }
             if(vid.paused){
                 vid.play();
                 btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
             }
             else{
                 vid.pause();
                 btn.innerHTML = "Play";
             }
         </script>
    <video id="ruqia_video1"  width="320" height="180" >
        <source src="videos/Rooqia01.mp4" />
    </video>
    <div id="video_controls_bar">
        <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="PlayPause(this, 'ruqia_video1' )">Pause</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you accept an answer or give additional informations about what still needs a fix?

Answer (score 1):

There were a few errors, but I made it working: https://jsfiddle.net/fu8eoofe/2/

Your function looked actually like this:

```
function playPause(btn, vid){
  var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
  vid.load();
}
```

It was closed before the if statements. Second thing is that you were calling a function named `PlayPause` when your function's name is `playPause`.

I replaced vid.paused with new variable for demonstration purposes (it wouldn't work without a video).

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors in your code.
corrected :

```
<style type="text/css">
        div#video_controls_bar {
            padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
         <script>
             function playPause(btn, vid){
                 var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
                 vid.load();

                 if(vid.paused){
                     vid.play();
                     btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
                 }
                 else{
                     vid.pause();
                     btn.innerHTML = "Play";
                 }
             }
         </script>
    <video id="ruqia_video1"  width="320" height="180" >
        <source src="videos/Rooqia01.mp4" />
    </video>
    <div id="video_controls_bar">
        <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause(this, 'ruqia_video1' )">Pause</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: A fixed version without an explanation is not as useful